Rails 7: How to escape turbo frame CSRF to redirect to a different subdomain?
I'm working on an app with Rails 7.2, Ruby 3.3.6, and turbo-rails 2.0.11.
There is a workflow that relies on a turbo-frame to update a portion of a page as it steps through several steps (different controller actions). At the first step after user input, one of the checks is that the user is using the correct subdomain of the app. If they are not, I want to redirect them to the correct subdomain:
redirect_to next_step_url(subdomain: correct_subdomain, email: workflow_params[:email]), allow_other_host: true

When I first tried this, nothing changes on the page and I note the following in the server logs:
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (HTTP Origin header (http://aflow.localhost:3000) didn't match request.base_url (http://bflow.localhost:3000))

actionpack (7.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:312:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (7.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:406:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (7.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:395:in `verify_authenticity_token'

At first I was confused, because redirecting to a different subdomain works elsewhere in the app with this syntax. After quite some time evaluating CORS, CSRF, etc, I realized with the help of this SO answer that the issue was related to turbo and the turbo-frame that the workflow occurs in. I can make it work by disabling turbo ( data: {turbo: false} ) on the preceding step, but then of course you lose turbo for all workflow users, not just the small minority that are using the wrong subdomain and need to be redirected to a different one.
I tried adding <meta name="turbo-visit-control" content="reload"> in the html  tag or the response, which is the suggested way to "break out" of a turbo frame in the documentation. But it doesn't change the result. It seems like the CSRF protection (outlined immediately after) trips before the header has a chance to force a reload. The only solution mentioned is to disable turbo for the request.
So, is there any way to redirect to a different subdomain from within a turbo-frame, without disabling turbo entirely?
